# Consider $f(x)=mx$ and $g(x) =bx$ in which $m>0$ and $b>0$. Does there exist any homeomorphism $h$ such that $h \circ f$ = $g \circ h$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Consider $f(x)=mx$ and $g(x) =bx$ in which $m>0$ and $b>0$. Does there exist any homeomorphism $h$ such that $h \circ f$ = $g \circ h$? If exists find the domain of $h$.
 
Obviously I tried $h(mx)=bh(x)$. But I don't know how to go for solving it! In addition, I have no idea about how to prove homeomorphism existence in such problems.

Comment: $h(x)=b^{\log_m(x)}$ works.

Comment: @M.Nestor How did you come up with such $h$?

Comment: I made a guess, since $\log$ satisfies $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$, then $\log_m(mx)=1+\log_m(x)$, then under exponentiation becomes $b\cdot b^{\log_{m}x}$, a good answer. Its inverse is $h^{-1}(x)=m^{\log_b(x)}$, so it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @M.Nestor Your function is only defined for $x > 0$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin That can be fixed by taking $x\mapsto|x|$, and setting $h(0)=0$.

Comment: @M.Nestor I am afraid you won't get a bijective function if you do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the domain of $f$ and $g$"? It looks like $f$ and $g$ are given real functions of domain $\Bbb{R}$. Do I miss something?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Fixed it. I meant find the domain of $h$

Comment: Still mysterious, since $h$ is supposed to be a homemorphism, and hence a bijection. Thus the domain of $h$ should also be $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin It is not! In this case the $h$ found is only valid for $x>0$ because of the logarithm involved!

Comment: Let $h(x)$  be as in M. Nestor's comment for positive $x$. Define $J(X)$ as follows: $J(X) = h(x)$ for $x>0$, $J(0)=0$, and $J(x) = - h( -x)$ for $x<0$. The function $J$ is bijective and continuous, as in the case $m=2, b=4$. Sorry I don't know how to format this stuff at all .

Comment: Also, the function $h(x)$ given above by M. Nestor is a power function, namely $h(x) = x^L$ where the constant $L$ is log base $m$ of $b$.

Comment: @Ned You sholud give an official answer. The ansatz $h(x) = x^L$ for $x \ge 0$ is suggestive and leads to $m^L = b$.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The question does not provide information about domains and ranges of the functions $f, g$. So let assume $f, g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. We ask  whether there exists a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $$(*) \quad h  \circ f = g \circ h .$$

Ned's comments show that a suggestive ansatz is

$$h(x) = \text{sgn}(x) \lvert x \rvert^L .$$
Here $L > 0$ is a real number which we can specify. Note that $h$ is in fact a homeomorphism since $L > 0$. (For $L \le 0$ the value $h(0)$ cannot not be defined by the above formula, but no matter which value we choose for $h(0)$: We never get a homeomorphism.)

$(*)$ is satisfied iff
$$m^L\text{sgn}(x)\lvert x \rvert^L = \text{sgn}(mx) \lvert mx \rvert^L = h(f(x)) = g(h(x)) = b\text{sgn}(x) \lvert x \rvert^L .$$
This is true iff $m^L = b$ which is equivalent to $L\ln m = \ln b$. Thus we must have

1. either $\ln m = \ln b = 0$ which is equivalent to $m = b = 1$ in which case $L$ is arbitrary,
2. or $\ln m, \ln b \ne 0$ which is equivalent to $m, b \ne 1$ in which case $L = \ln b / \ln m$. Note that to achieve $L > 0$ we must require that both $m, b > 1$ or both $m, b < 1$.

This shows that the ansatz works provided the above conditions on $m,b$ are satisfied.

What about the cases not covered by our ansatz? These are

1. $m = 1, b \ne 1$
2. $m \ne 1, b = 1$
3. $m < 1, b > 1$
4. $m > 1, b < 1$

Let us first observe that solutions of $(*)$ are never unique. In fact, if $h$ satisfies $(*)$, then also $h' = ch$ with $c \ne 0$ satisfies $(*)$ because $h'(f(x)) = ch(f(x)) = cg(h(x)) = cbh(x) = bch(x) =bh'(x) = g(h'(x))$. In case $m = b = 1$ we even see that *each* homeomorphism $h$ is a solution of $(*)$.

Let us verify that in cases 1. - 4. there does not exist a solution of $(*)$.

1. If $m = 1$, then $f = id$ and we must have $h = h \circ f = g \circ h$, i.e. $g = id$ which is not true for $b \ne 1$.
2. This is treated as 1.
3. Assume $(*)$ has a solution $h$. Then $h(0) = h(f(0)) = g(h(0)) = b h(0)$ which implies $h(0) = 0$ since $b \ne 1$. We may assume that $h$ is strictly increasing (in case it is strictly decreasing, consider $h' = -h$ which is also a  solution). For $x > 0$ we have $0 < mx < x$, thus $0 = h(0) < h(mx) < h(x)$ which implies $h(f(x)) < h(x) < b h(x) = g(h(x))$, a contradiction.
4. This is treated similarly as 3.